# How to export HTML table with Urdu text(Unicode) to PDF?

Tags: html, jspdf, urdu

I have a HTML table with Urdu text. I exported it in PDF using jspdf but it did not show urdu characters.

HTML Table with Urdu heading:

[image]

Output PDF as:

[image]

Comment: Can you try ``ctrl + p`` on windows or ``command + p`` on MacOS. It will show the print preview. If it is visible there then you have a workaround of saving it manually.

Comment: Can you host it somewhere? So that i can check

Comment: @MansoorAhmed, please put your code to your question. Use "edit" link below your question.

Comment: @SandipNirmal thanks for comment. and I have tried with ctrl+p on windows, it is visible. I can save manually through print but i need to save with a separate  button.

Comment: Can you have code hosted somewhere so that I can try. Fiddle or something

Comment: No I am using on localhost.